# Problem with adding texture to an imported objext

Tags: texturing, objects, import

I have imported an object from Roblox studio to Blender. However, the object appears white even though I have the .mtl file. I don't know how to fix this problem. I would be really glad if anyone helped me out with this issue.

The shader editor looks like this,[image]

Comment: Hello, how does the Shader Editor look like?

Comment: Edited and added the image of shader editor.

Comment: is it supposed to display a texture? because for the moment no Image Texture is plugged into the Principled BSDF